# What is the difference between ng-init and controller initialization?

Tags: angularjs

There are two ways to initialize a variable in Angular.

one way is using **ng-init**:

```
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="" ng-init="firstName='John'">
            <p>Name: {{ firstName }}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

another way is using **controller**:

```
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <body>
        <p ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            Name: {{ firstName }}
        </p>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
            app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
                $scope.firstName = "John";
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The former is simpler than later but, I think the second one is more common.

So what is the difference between these ways and which one is better?

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample

**ng-init:**

The purpose of **ng-init** is initialize a property in template.
The difference is that when you have the ng-init in the HTML, the `init()` function will only be called during the actual render of the page. If for any reason that content needs to be re-rendered, the `init()` function will be called again.

**controller:**

AngularJS application mainly relies on controllers to control the flow of data in the application. A **controller** is defined using ng-controller directive. A controller is a JavaScript object that contains attributes/properties, and functions.

Comment: So using controller is better because we can re-render the page with initializing, right?

Comment: controller is good to pass the data and ng-init for intialize and onload function call